# prevent modalpopup closing on postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a `textbox`, button and `gridview` inside `jquery` modal popup. On page load I display the modal popup and enter a value in textbox then click button. In code-behind I wrote some functionality to calculate something and displayed it in the gridview but the modal popup should not close. In my case, while post back the modal popup closed. I'am not using `modalpopupextender` and update panel, without using `modalpopup` extender and update panel how to prevent modal popup closing while post back?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way would be, but you can try setting a flag of sorts and using that on the page load. Something like `if (IsPostBack && ShowPopup) { /* show popup */ }`.

Comment: I think you need to do this by using jQuery ajax, So no postback thing occurs,  well post your code, this put more light to understand us better

Comment: This is my modal popup calling script for your reference.                                   $('#lnk').click(function () {
                $("#IsPopupOpened").val("1");
                var mydiv = $('#ImageUploadDiv');
                mydiv.dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 800, height: 700, modal: true });
                // Load the content using AJAX
                mydiv.load('IncomePotential.aspx');

                
                // Open the dialog
                mydiv.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

Comment: Thanks jonB. Your idea works.